# C- Efficient code vs Good Code

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am learning C, and so far have a decent understanding of the language, I recently implemented a singly linked list which is pretty simple. I had watched a Ted Talks with Linus Torvalds, he had mentioned good code vs bad code and provided these two examples of removing an entry from a linked list:

```
/*bad code*/
remove_list_entry(entry){
    prev = NULL;
    walk = head;

    while(walk != entry){
        prev = walk;
        walk = walk->next;
    }

    if(!prev)
         head = entry->next;
    else
         prev->next = entry->next;


/*good code*/
remove_list_entry(entry){
    indirect = &head;

    while ((*indirect) != entry)
        indirect = &(*indirect)->next;

    *indirect = entry->next;
}
```

It seems to me that his example of good code is efficient, but I wouldn't have figured this out myself. Is there any recommendations for good practice while programming in C that I can follow? Or certain ways to manipulated pointers as he did in his example? As well as bad habits and practices to avoid while programming in C.I hope this isn't too broad of a question.

Comment: This is too broad question. Please ask question that can be clearly answered.

Comment: I don't know if it is too broad but maybe you must find better answers in Code Review community.

Comment: It probably _is_ too broad. Get some well-reviewed books on best practice, and read some well-regarded code to pick up useful idioms. Spend a few years doing this as well as coding, going back to look at what you wrote with a critical eye, and eventually ...

Comment: The second form should probably have been: `while ( *indirect && *indirect != entry)
        indirect = &(*indirect)->next;`

Comment: @BenZotto This question is not a good fit for Software Engineering - please don't recommend sites - when poor questions are posted on Software Engineering, they end up down voted, closed, and deleted very quickly and this leads to a poor user experience.

Comment: experience. Watch presentations like that one, watch more presentations by experienced and passionate programmers. Write code. Write a lot of code. Reinvent the wheel if the process of building the wheel is challenging. Write more code. Come back to code you wrote last year and improve it with the knowledge and experience you gained meanwhile.

Comment: can't tell you how many times I've come back to code I wrote in the past and completely refactored it or tried a different approach.

Comment: Keep in mind that Linus Torvalds is behind the Linux kernel, which has turned out to be one of the ugliest code bases ever written in C. I'd be very sceptical to anything he says about what he considers to be good style.

Comment: Also, given that `indirect` is a pointer, how will `&(*indirect)->next` even compile? Is it a pointer to a pointer? Must be. What a mess.

Comment: @Lundin pointers-to-pointers are both possible and rather common in pure C programs of any complexity. They behave exactly as you'd imagine but do require you to use another layer of mental indirection.

Comment: @BenZotto On the contrary, they are quite rare in pure C programs. Most often they are used for obfuscation purposes or by beginners who don't understand pointers and 2D arrays very well. The only valid use of them is pretty much to alter a pointer passed as parameter to a function. Which doesn't seem to be the case here. It rather seems to be global variable.

Comment: IMO, both functions are bad as it is not hard to code a LL solution that inserts and remove in O(1) time rather than use an O(n) remove solution.  Hence the problem of focusing on looks and read-ability vs design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular example from Linus demonstrates how to avoid branches by using indirection. The two separate code paths represented by `head = entry->next` and `prev->next = entry->next` can be united into one by using a pointer to the thing that is being assigned to: `*indirect = entry->next`.

This approach can lead to very elegant, linear code with fewer branches.

The general pattern is that you can turn this code:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;

if (some_condition) {
    a = 1;
} else if (other_condition) {
    b = 1;
}

/* continue working with "a" and "b" */
```

Into:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
int *p;

if (some_condition) {
    p = &a;
} else if (other_condition) {
    p = &b;
} else {
    p = NULL;
}

/* consequently, work only with "*p" and never again touch "a" or "b" */
if (p) {
    *p = 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you, that answers part of my questions to why he wrote his code like that.

Comment: It is not only branches and code paths, but also the amount of (temp) variables that need to be maintained.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my short answer: you're not wrong, but neither is Linus. I am an experienced programmer with a lot of work in C and I find his version of this linked list code basically unreadable. I would never write this code myself.

He used this example not so much to show OK vs. not-OK, but to demonstrate how clearer thinking about a problem can lead to solutions that are more compact and have fewer edge cases (and conditional flows) to consider and test. On that score, his is an improvement.

"Readability" is typically cited as a first-order consideration in modern programming, so that both you and others can understand quickly what code is trying to achieve. This is traded off against complexity and performance considerations, but it's up to you to make that trade-off.

Comment: I think the first version is both error prone and unreadable. Looks like Java ...

Comment: @joop: Fair enough, and so thus we would make different tradeoffs when approaching this problem.

Comment: I have edited out your suggestion to cross-post this question on Software Engineering. It is not a good fit. Please refrain from suggesting that people cross-post their questions, especially when they would be down voted, closed, and/or deleted on the other site.